# Method not found using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (2.0.3.0)

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I just upgraded Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage from [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) and  I'm getting strange errors in Visual Studio 2010.

When calling my method `IncrementCountProperty` from the method `AddEntry` i get the following error:

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty..ctor(Int64)'.
```

(Stack)

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty..ctor(Int64)'.
   at App.MyClass.IncrementCountProperty(Int32 companyId, String feedKey, Int64 incrementCount)
   at App.MyClass.AddEntry(Int32 companyId, String feedKey, FeedEntry entry) in C:\xxx\MyFile.cs:line 464
```

I realise I'm doing something wrong in `IncrementCountProperty` but the strange part is, that Visual Studio won't recognize any breakpoints in the `IncrementCountProperty` method. If I put a breakpoint on the calling line in AddEntry, breakpoints works fine. If I then hit F11 to step into, I get the exception directly.  Both are declared in the same class

I've tried the following:

- Removing all pdb files
- Removing the projects dlls in bin/debug
- Ran Clean on the solution
- Restarted Visual Stuido
- Restared my computer
- Throwing an exception in IncrementCountProperty method just to make sure my code is actually called. And the exception is being thrown. But no debugger.

I've also verified that the correct version of the WindowsAzure storage is being used, both by version number and by using the ILDASM tool.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you check the path of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll (using a tool such as 'ProcExp /e') and check the dll there? Maybe it's not what you expect? Also, there is a 2.0.4.0 version available.

Answer (score 3):

It's working!

After updating to `WindowsAzure.Storage 2.0.4.1` it is working. I've been trying with `2.0.4.0` since shortly after I wrote the question. The 26th microsoft released revision 1 which references `Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0` (instead of `5.0.2`).

My gut tells me this was the issue.